# How to change the size of a point in pst-solides3d?

Tags: pst-solides3d

In the following document, I want to decrease the radius of the sphere representing the point.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[viewpoint=30 40 30 rtp2xyz] (-2,-1) (2,2)
  \psSolid[object=point,
  args=0 0 0.5]
  \axesIIID (0,0,0) (1,1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this using the `object=point` key, which only takes the coordinates as arguments, but you can add points using `\psPoint` plus `\psdots` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[viewpoint=30 40 30 rtp2xyz] (-2,-1) (2,2)
  \psSolid[object=point, args=0 0 0.5]
\psPoint(0,0,.25){P}
\psdots[dotsize=0.1](P)
  \axesIIID (0,0,0) (1,1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Could you change this line?
args=0 0 0.5] % the 0.5 value?

Comment: @JohnSmith Not sure what you mean.  The `0 0 0.5` is the x,y,z coordinates of the point. So `.5` puts the point halfway up the z axis as shown in the image.